# How to get a file only?

Tags: vb6

How to get a file name only from file's full path?

```
MY path -  C:\Documents and Settings\Arshad\My Documents\ravi.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this: **[Retrieve Filename without Path or Extension](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1638).**

Here's the function from the above link:

```
Public Function GetFileName(flname As String) As String

    'Get the filename without the path or extension.
    'Input Values:
    '   flname - path and filename of file.
    'Return Value:
    '   GetFileName - name of file without the extension.

    Dim posn As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim fName As String

    posn = 0
    'find the position of the last "\" character in filename
    For i = 1 To Len(flname)
        If (Mid(flname, i, 1) = "\") Then posn = i
    Next i

    'get filename without path
    fName = Right(flname, Len(flname) - posn)

    'get filename without extension
    posn = InStr(fName, ".")
        If posn <> 0 Then
            fName = Left(fName, posn - 1)
        End If
    GetFileName = fName
End Function
```

When inputting

> `C:\Documents and Settings\Arshad\My Documents\ravi.txt`

this function returns

> `ravi`

The function is called as such:

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = GetFileName("C:\Documents and Settings\Arshad\My Documents\ravi.txt")
```

Comment: I updated the post. The article I linked to in the first place, has a code snippet that does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest way:

```
Public Function GetFileName(FilePath As String) As String
   Dim l() as string
   l=split(FilePath,"\")
   GetFileName=l(UBound(l))
End Function
```

Tell me, if you can find shorter code;)

Comment: this would not remove any file extensions from a filename

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=475667

Answer (score 0):

-

Here are the better and short way.

**Return file name from FullPath**

```
' ** C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe > Ret: calc.exe
Private Function GetFilenameFromPath(FullPath As String) As String
   GetFilenameFromPath = Right(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - InStrRev(FullPath, "\"))
End Function
```

**Return Path from FullPath**

```
' C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe > Ret: C:\Windows\System32\
Private Function GetDirectoryFromPath(FullPath As String) As String
   GetDirectoryFromPath = Left(FullPath, InStrRev(FullPath, "\"))
End Function
```